# Can we get all the links on the page Using Watin

Tags: watin, html-agility-pack, coded-ui-tests

Is is possible to get all the Links on the page using WatiN.  I found it pretty easy in [html agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) but i have to use [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `Browser.Links` methods

```
using(Browser browser = new IE("http://www.sp4ce.net"))
{
    foreach(Link link in browser.Links)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(link);
    }
}
```